# PostgreSQL escape character during copy

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, escaping, psql

I'm trying to import a CSV file into PostgreSQL but I am having an issue with special characters.

I'm using the following command

```
./psql -d data -U postgres -c "copy users from 'users.csv' delimiter E'\t' quote '~' csv"
```

It works fine until it encounters a field with the '~' which I'm using as a quote value to not break the existing quotes and inverted commas etc.

How do I escape this character in the csv file 'Person~name' so that it will import as 'Person~name'

Comment: show simple example how your CSV format looks like and which PostgreSQK version you use. I can't recreate error on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV rules are listed in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

To embed the quote character inside a string:

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>         appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>         another double quote.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"

In your case, replace double-quote by tilde, since you've choosen that delimiter.

Example:

```
test=> create table copytest(t text);
CREATE TABLE

test=> \copy copytest from stdin delimiter E'\t' quote '~' csv
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> ~foo~~bar~
>> \.

test=> select * from copytest;
   t    
---------
 foo~bar
```